# Page breaking up for caption of a table

Tags: tables, page-breaking, captions

Using the following I get problem by page break up.

```
\IfFileExists{FILE}{%
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Grenzwertverletzung [AL9]}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
 AL9&  \input{FILE} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}{}


\IfFileExists{FILE}{%
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Caption is [AR07]}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
 AR07&  \input{FILE} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}{}
```

[image]

Comment: I would just like to add that non-floating table will _always_ cause you troubles, because they are too large and the pages will become "too empty" if you don't allow your table to float.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\captionof{table}{Grenzwertverletzung [AL9]}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
 AL9&  \input{FILE} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

will keep them together (but better really to use a table environment and let LaTeX move it away from the page break).